# Русские символы в форме Spring MVC

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring-mvc, utf-8, кодировка

Всем привет! (РЕШЕНИЕ ЕСТЬ)

Я понимаю, эта не первой свежести тема....

Столкнулся в Spring MVC с проблемой Encoding, "utf8"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы решить эту проблему я пересмотрел много ответов, что я делал:

1. В конфигурации Spring MVC **добавил фильтр** public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends
   AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {......

```
 @Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    Filter[] filters;
    CharacterEncodingFilter encFilter;
    HiddenHttpMethodFilter httpMethodFilter = new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();
    encFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    encFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    encFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    filters = new Filter[] {httpMethodFilter, encFilter};
    return filters;
}
```

2. В конфигурации Spring Security **добавил фильтр** public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter    {...

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new EncodingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
......
Сам фильтр:

public class EncodingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

3. Я использую Thymeleaf, **в классе настроек представления** я добавил нужную информацию

```
@Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver springTemplateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver springTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        springTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

...

@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

...
```

4. В конфигурации **источника данных** я также указал

а. свойства строки подключения:

```
try {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqlo?" +
                    "useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true" +
                    "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false" +
                    "&serverTimezone=UTC" +
                    "&useSSL=false" +
                    "&useUnicode=true" +
                    "&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci" +
                    "&characterSetResults=utf8" +
                    "&characterEncoding=utf-8");

Пробовал **useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"** - не помогло
```

b. Свойства hibernate

```
@Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
....

//Кодировка
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", true);
```

5. Сделал настройку Томкат **в файле server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

6. Настройку Maven сделал

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
...
<plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
...
    <configuration>
                   <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                   <source>8</source>
...
```

7. Теги кодировки на страницах html добавил

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
```

8. В настройках самой базы стоят следующие параметры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В свойствах таблиц настройки следующие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

9. Сами файлы html я проверил в формате UTF-8 сохранены.
   Дополнения:
   9.1 Файлы классов тоже в формате UTF-8
10. Кодировку в IDEJ, проверил UTF-8
11. Кодировка при отправке браузером также проверена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

12. При отадке уточнил, запрос в контроллер попадает уже никакой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

13. Сам контроллер:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/vend.new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newVendor (@ModelAttribute("newvend") @Valid Vendor vend, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
       if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "ok";
        }
        sv.getInsertVokmar(vend);
        return "ok";
    }
```

***При тестировании проекта я обнаружил, фильтры при инициализации, создаются, регистрируются:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***При получении запроса в контроллере фильтры куда-то пропадают:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версии банок:

```
<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
<jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
<spring.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
<tld.version>1.1.2</tld.version>
<servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
<jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
<hibernate.version>5.4.10.Finall</hibernate.version>
<kotlin.version>1.0.0</kotlin.version>
```

> **Очень, прошу подсказать, где ошибка и что я делаю не так**.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding

Comment: Я использую Thymeleaf, на уровне страниц я использую <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /> - это не помогло

Comment: Сейчас, после просмотра поста, который прислал Николай Гнап я буду пробовать следующее: в idea сменить настройку кодировки (Установите кодировку ресурса в UTF-8, в случае, если вы пишете любые символы UTF-8 в коде Java или JSP напрямую.) https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/. Если есть предложения, буду рад!

Answer (score 1):

Решение для моего случая:

1. Я обратил внимание что регистрация фильтров, которые отвечают за правильный вывод символов (Русские) при использовании **Spring Security** должна производится в конфигурации Spring Security, скорее всего это определенная особенность, которую ещё предстоит выяснить мне (если кто знает, прошу поделится опытом)
2. Я удалил всю регистрацию фильтров из класса (пункт 1 моего вопроса):

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {......
 @Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
.....
```

3. Я изменил фильтр в классе регистрации безопасности public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {... (пункт 2 моего вопроса)

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new EncodingFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
....

public class EncodingFilterConfig implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
```

После данных изменений все работает.
Вопрос остался в понимании сути этой строки 
http.addFilterBefore(new EncodingFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
а точнее в классе ChannelProcessingFilter.class - я понял это стандартный класс из системы безопасности ([список классов безопасности](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ae6af5d73ce77f93926379f96371e84b1e9401f1/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterComparator.java#L61)) и для регистрации моего класса фильтра мне нудно добавить мой фильтр перед этим (есть еще несколько методов http.addFilte...)

Answer (score 0):

`<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` вот это в jsp, и в web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
 Я не использую web.xml,  как я понял, то что вы написали из web.xml можно реализовать программно, я это делаю как указал в пункте 1, пожалуйста посмотрите этот пункт, может в нем есть ошибка. Я уже понимаю, что через фильтры решается мой вопрос, но в коде пункта 1 я не вижу ошибок. Хотя я не понимаю, нужно ли как-то регистрировать фильтр которые я установил в пункте 1 моего вопроса или добавив метод getServletFilters() происходит автоматическая регистрация?

Comment: В процессе тестирования я обнаружил ошибку, я добавил ее в конце своего вопроса, фильтры создаются а при поступлении запроса к контроллеру их уже нет. Как такое может быть, может это из-за  Spring Security, если нет, посмотрите на установку фильтров, что я делаю не так?